# 'from extension import utils' giving error in AWS Glue Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, boto3, aws-glue

In AWS Glue Jupyter Notebook, When I run the command `from extension import utils` i get error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'extension'`

Below is the complete list of things that I have to import, Only the last one I am getting error.

```
import time
import boto3
import logging 

from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *

import pyarrow as pa
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from extension import utils
```

Screenshot:
[image]

I tried `!pip install extension` but don't know whats going on.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in order to add additional libraries you can use `%additional_python_modules` option in notebook. You can give pypi packages or   s3 location of packages.

Second, I dont see utils class in any of extension/extensions/pyextension packages. Can you double check the package.? If its internal package, i suggest using s3 option.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have not installed `extension` module.

You can add install the module by adding the following in the previous cell.

```
!pip3 install extension
```

Comment: I tried this, But I think it doesn't work, Can you please look at the second screenshot?

Comment: try `pip3` instead of `pip`